# How to send JSON in Redis stream NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, redis-streams

I am creating one script where I want some dummy data to send to redis server using streams.
For that, I am using "ioredis" module for Redis stream.
Its working fine when I send simple key value structure i.e `{a:"hello",b:"world"}`.

But **not** working for Json array structure.

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "ts": 123,
    "lists": [{
        "oil": "1",
        "food": "1,
        "item": "1"
    }]

}
```

It throws errors like

```
throw new Error(`Data type of property ${key} is not supported.`);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis Streams don't do JSON. They *do* allow key-value data to be associated with each event. Note that both the key and the value must be strings.

[ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) does this with variadic arguments for the keys and values. There's an [example](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/main/examples/stream.js) on the ioredis repo but here's the bit you probably care about:

```js
client.xadd("user-stream", "*", "name", "John", "age", "20")
```

[Node Redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) has a different syntax that allows you to pass in a JavaScript object. But, that object must be flat and full of strings. There's an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/examples/stream-producer.js) but here's the tl;dr:

```js
client.xAdd('user-stream', '*', { name: "John", age: "20" })
```

Also, note, that in *both* cases, the function is `async` so you can `await` it if you like.

If you want to store JSON in an event in a Stream in Redis, you'll need to stringify it first:

```js
const data = JSON.stringify({
  "name": "abc",
  "ts": 123,
  "lists": [{
    "oil": "1",
    "food": "1",
    "item": "1"
  }]
})

/* if you use ioredis */
client.xadd("user-stream", "*", "data", data)

/* if you use Node Redis */
client.xAdd('user-stream', '*', { data })
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

JSON is not a valid [data type](https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/) for Redis out of the box.

There are some alternatives.

- You can serialize the JSON structure into a string and store that string into Redis. When you later recover it from Redis, you need to deserialize it into your JSON structure.
- Include [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) in your Redis installation. A module that provides JSON support in Redis.

Answer (score 1):

[Node Redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) has a neat solution to this [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/dbf8f59a47573e6a1c75b78e566af8c493015d5d/packages/client/lib/commands/XADD.ts#L45). You might consider using the same in [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) as follows:

```
const args = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(reportingRequest)) {
  args.push(key, value);
}
client.xadd(REDIS_STREAM_KEY, '*', ...args);
```